# Étymologie de "rembarrer"

Tags: étymologie

Le Petit Robert me dit

> ÉTYM. XVème. de re- et embarrer «enfoncer»

et que "embarrer" date du XIIème siècle, en passant. D'un autre coté, sur la [page du Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/rembarrer), les références historiques les plus vieilles pour «rembarrer» datent du 16ème siècle. Quelle est donc cette référence du 15ème siècle sur laquelle le Petit Robert se baserait?

Answer (score 1):

Selon le [*Trésor de la langue française informatisé*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/rembarrer), une attestation datant de 1476, retrouvée dans les *Archives du Nord*, B 1698, f° 2 ds IGLF.

[Cet utilisateur](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3177) au nom changeant, plus débrouillard que moi, a su trouver en ligne plus d’information concernant ce sigle [IGLF](http://stella.atilf.fr/TLF/TLFBib1.pdf) *(Inventaire Général de la Langue Française)*, plus précisément à la page 186 de [ce document](https://en.calameo.com/read/000903947487ecce803db?authid=vmvA56zEmzku) (ou à la page 97 en utilisant l’outil de navigation de la page).

On y apprend là qu’il fut quelques années après sa création rattaché au *Trésor de la Langue Française*.

> L’*Inventaire Général de la Langue Française*, fondé et dirigé jusqu’à sa mort (1961) par Mario Roques, dirigé jusqu’au 31 décembre 1968 par M. F. Lecoy, Professeur au Collège de France et maintenant rattaché au Trésor de la Langue Française, est un fichier de type classique, comprenant un peu plus de six millions d’exemples illustrant des mots français.
>
> Ces exemples sont empruntés à des oeuvres de toute nature et de toutes périodes de l’histoire de la Langue française : textes littéraires (de la *Chanson de Roland* aux œuvres de Giono), textes techniques (traités de médecine ou catalogues du *Bon Marché*), textes d’argot. Sans prétendre à l’exhaustivité dans le choix des textes et encore moins dans le dépouillement des textes retenus, l’intention avait été de présenter un large ensemble documentaire qui permit d’étudier le vocabulaire dans tous les domaines où s’est manifestée la civilisation française.
>
> L’I.G.L.F. est classé par auteurs, eux-mêmes classés dans l’ordre chronologique sauf pour les textes techniques, qui sont classés par spécialités. Sous cette forme, il a été installé par Mario Roques à Paris [...] où le classement par auteurs est mis au point et où il peut être consulté [...].
>
> Les collaborateurs de l’*Inventaire* (plus de 200 en un quart de siècle) étaient des étudiants, des professeurs, des artistes, des secrétaires, des spécialistes divers, choisis à raison d’aptitudes, d’affinités ou simplement de goûts personnels. Pour chaque texte, ils avaient mission d’établir des fiches avec un contexte allant jusqu’à 6 ou 7 lignes pour chacun des mots qui, à un titre quelconque, leur paraissaient dignes d’intérêt.
>
> L’expérience montre que l’*Inventaire* gagnait dans l’ordre de la qualité ce qui lui manque dans celui de la quantité. C’est ainsi que par ex. le fichier *Barrès* (cote QI), une des pièces maîtresses de 1’*Inventaire*, a été établi par M<sup>lle</sup> R. Robert, dernière Secrétaire de l’auteur.
>
> Un double a été réalisé par le service photographique (M. Bastardi) du centre de documentation du C.N.R.S. (15, quai Anatole France, Paris). Transféré à Nancy, dans les locaux du *Centre de recherche pour un Trésor de la langue Française* (44, avenue de la Libération — téléphone 52.04.70), ce double a subi à Nancy un traitement manuel, puis mécanographique en cours, en vue d’un interclassement alphabétique intégral.

La mention *Archives du Nord* pour l’attestation de 1476 me semble à première vue, mais sous toutes réserves, pointer vers un document légal ou administratif.